# Write Java Bean Class work correctly with the setProperty

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I want to write a Java Bean Class called **Car** that will work correctly with the setProperty tag.  The class I need should include a boolean method to validate the form data. Can anyone please write:

1. Correct example how to write a Java Bean Class called **Car** that will work correctly with the setProperty tag.
2. Write boolean method to validate the form data

Comment: I have re edited my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your javabean must respect the javabeans specifications to work correctly.
(For instance, no parameters in the constructor)

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-javadoc-oth-JSpec/